# Draft JS: hide the cursor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I'm trying to hide the cursor in draft-js. I want it to function as normal but the user not to be able to see the blinking cursor, is there any way of doing this in draft JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `caret-color` which is support by all modern browser nowadays: https://caniuse.com/?search=caret-color

```css
    .public-DraftStyleDefault-block {
        caret-color: transparent;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any way to hide just the cursor and leave the text as the color it is?  or is that what this does?

Comment: Found a better solution, `caret-color` and updated the answer!

Comment: brilliant, thanks so much. one thing: overriding the CSS like that didn't work for me but it did work when i set blockStyleFn={() => "my-css-class"} in the Editor class and then define "my-css-class" in a separate css file